# Definir dinamicamente o tamanho de coluna do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou trabalhando com a geração de planilhas em EXCEL, e para isto eu utilizo a api padrao do framework.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Entretanto, quando tenho uma coluna com texto muito extenso, a linha é quebrada a cada palavra ou de acordo com o tamanho do titulo do cabecalho. Gostaria de saber, como tornar isto mais agradável visualmente. Existe alguma maneira de atribuir dinamicamente a largura das colunas do excel, de forma que fiquem visivelmente mais agradaveis?

Estou tentando utilizar o autofit, mas parece nao surtir o efeito desejado.

```
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.Rows.AutoFit()
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
```

[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o seguinte comando para ajustar automaticamente a largura da coluna de acordo com os textos que preenchem suas linhas:

```
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Para o exemplo eu ajustei o tamanho da coluna `C` apenas, entretanto você pode definir um range de todas as colunas que deseja auto ajustar.

Comment: Eu ja tentei este comando, mas nao funcionou como eu queria. Consegui "resolver" o problema, aumentando o titulo da coluna.

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro esse comando somente não auto ajusta colunas que possui células mescladas, seria esse seu caso? sugiro que você mescle o mínimo possível, talvez somente o título

Answer (score 2):

Em código similar, consegui realizar o ajuste das células do cabeçalho -range ("A1:Z1") - corretamente. Antes de realizar o comando de autofit, deve-se configurar as células para alimentação de linha automática (.wrapText), e as colunas devem ter sua largura ajustadas para um valor menor que a menor largura final. No exemplo abaixo, a menor largura final, dentre todas as colunas, era maior do que 12. 
Vejam o exemplo:

```
    Plan2Dados.Rows("1:1").WrapText = True
    Plan2Dados.Columns("A:Z").ColumnWidth = 12
    Plan2Dados.Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
```

Answer (score 1):

tente:

```
Worksheets("Plan1").Columns.AutoFit
```

ou

**`'A:I`** pode ser substituído pelo intervalo que desejar.

```
Worksheets("Plan1").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
```

Answer (score -1):

bom dia pessoal, não estou respondendo a pergunta pois entre todas, a unica resposta que funcionou pra mim foi a do Roberto Santos.

```
 Plan1.Rows("1:1").WrapText = True
 Plan1.Columns("A:Z").ColumnWidth = 12
 Plan1.Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
```

Apenas ajustei para minha 'Plan1', tentei todas possiveis e apenas essa funcionou, parabens Roberto.